# How can i bring a process handle window to front but in normal size not maximize?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of the class I have:

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr handle, int nCmdShow);
    private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
```

Then in a method:

```
public static void BringToFront(IntPtr handle)
        {
            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            // Maximize window
            ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }
```

But I don't want it to be maximized but normal size.

EDIT

This is working.

In form1:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
SetProcessWindow.BringToFront(processes[0].Id);
SetProcessWindow.CenterProcessWindow(processes[0].Id);
```

In the class:

```
public static void BringToFront(int processId)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;

            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }
```

Comment: You could use  SW_SHOWNORMAL     = 1; instead of SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED

Comment: Tried the SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1; and it didn't show anything. Didn't bring the window to the front at all. Also tried 2 nothing 3 is maximized also 4 maximized. Strange that SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1; doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could find something useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468331/showwindow-function-doesnt-work-when-target-application-is-run-as-administrator

Answer (score 1):

Use SW_SHOW = 5 instead of SW_SHOWMAIXMIZED.

Incidentally, [this was the first link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) when I did a search for SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED.... Got to smarten up those research muscles!

Comment: Tried it now too nothing it didn't bring the window to the front at all.